# SurfaceView execute method while finger touches the screen

Tags: android, surfaceview, touch-event

This is most likely a trivial stuff but I can't find a solution for it.
Things are simple, the user presses the screen and while he is holding the finger on the screen I want a piece of code to execute.

Here is a code sample:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (getHolder()) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        myobject.setX(myobject.getX() - 10);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The effect of this code is that myobject.setX() only happens once, I want it to keep repeating while the user keeps the finger on the screen, so if it holds it for 3 seconds, myobject.setX() would decrease with -10 a few times.

Comment: By returning true at the end, you might disabled further propagation of events, change the return statement to false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (example):

```
int howLongUntilEdge = 1000;
CountDownTimer t = new CountDownTimer(howLongUntilEdge, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        myobject.setX(myobject.getX() - 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {}
};
```

then on your touch event:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (getHolder()) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            t.start();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            t.stop();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It would move it left by 10 every second. You would need to do something like decide how many seconds until it would reach the edge and set the `howLongUntilEdge` var to reflect the correct value

Comment: I like this approach most. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. One thing to watch out for - onTouchEvent with ACTION_UP might not be run in some rare cases, for example, if you get a phone call while you have it pressed down. You might want to also stop the timer onPause of your fragment/activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean variable (assigned to true on ACTION_DOWN) to indicate that you still pressing the screen, and when you raise your finger (ACTION_UP), you set it to false, so during this you can start a Thread to execute your code much time you want, like this:

```
private boolean mIsStillPressing;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (getHolder()) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mIsStillPressing = true;
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Still moving object until an ACTION_UP is done.
                    while (mIsStillPressing) {
                        myobject.setX(myobject.getX() - 10);

                        // Some sleep time
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mIsStillPressing = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) provided in `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` will only match `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` for the initial touch.  You'll need to continue your updates in your else if statement: `(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)`.